# Finding acceleration using components method

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, velocity

The problem I am working on gives me an initial velocity of 2[E15N] m/s and a final velocity of 4[E35N] m/s after 30s. I need to find acceleration so I create a right angle triange for both of these vectors, and subtracted their respective hypotenuse. But what would the direction be?

Comment: You may want to clarify what your notation `2[E15N]` means. So far you have two answers and two different interpretations

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your strange notation means E15N: "15 degrees North of East", and E35N: "35 degrees North of East".

In that case, the following diagram should help (I deliberately left it incomplete, so you have to do a bit of the work yourself...)

[image]

The vector whose magnitude and direction you try to determine is the red one - the difference between the final velocity and the initial one. Of course you need to divide the length (the change in velocity) by the time (30 seconds) to get the magnitude of the acceleration - but if I understood your notation correctly, this should give the direction.